# How can I make a Playstation 3 Game card?

Tags: javascript, playstation

I want to make a ps3 card like this one:

http://gamercards.exophase.com/2516.png

using the data from the ps3 network site, this one

http://us.playstation.com/publictrophy/index.htm?onlinename=bruno_shady

but I want to make something different, something that show only the name of the person and the games that the person has, to post on a forum that I frequent...

How can I do it, or what do I need to do it?
something simple would be nice, and that it update itself from one to one day, or even more, two, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a server side language to do that - like PHP.

You will need:

- A way of catch the data from the PlayStation website. It can be done quite easy using the curl library and RegExps.
- A way of compose the final image. You should have one or more base image(s). You will need to load the image with a image library like GD in PHP and draw on it the necessary text.
- A cache system. Actually it not necessary but your server will waste too much resource otherwise. It's about of saving the generated image in the hard disk at the first request and send it on every request, with a refrest rate of some hours or days.